# Display the total amount from TextView values in a Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a shopping cart in my app, and I have been wondering how would I be able to get the sum of the values from the textviews in my listview, and then display it in another class?

That **orderTotal** array is the amount of quantity of products in each row

This is My Adapter Class:

```
public class ListCartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context context;


private ArrayList<String> orderTotal;

public ListCartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> orderTotal){
    this.context = context;
    this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return orderName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return orderName.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  final cartDatabaseHelper db = new cartDatabaseHelper(context);

    final View listView;
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_list_item, null);

  TextView total = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.textOrderTotal);

    total.setText(orderTotal.get(position));

    return listView;
}
```

And this is MainActivity class:

```
//CART LISTVIEW
private ArrayList<String> orderid;
private ArrayList<String> orderName;
private ArrayList<String> orderSize;
private ArrayList<String> orderQuantity;
private ArrayList<String> orderTotal;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    //CART LISTVIEW
    orderid = new ArrayList<>();
    orderName = new ArrayList<>();
    orderSize = new ArrayList<>();
    orderQuantity = new ArrayList<>();
    orderTotal = new ArrayList<>();

    TextView textTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOrderSumTotal);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ListCartAdapter adapter = new ListCartAdapter(cart.this, orderid, orderName, orderSize, orderQuantity, orderTotal);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Cursor data = db.getListContents();

    if(data.getCount() == 0){
        btnCheckout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        btnCheckout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        data.moveToFirst();
        do{
            orderid.add(data.getString(0));
            orderName.add(data.getString(1));
            orderSize.add(data.getString(2));
            orderQuantity.add(data.getString(3));
            orderTotal.add(data.getString(4));
        } while (data.moveToNext());
    }
    data.close();

    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));

}
```

The textTotal is where I am planning to display the total of the values from the listview.

Can anybody point me to the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is orderTotal array list?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to explain that. The orderTotal is the amount of each product in the listview sir

Comment: what do you mean by total? is it the total quantity of items? or the no. of products?

Comment: so u need the total number of items..ex: if someboby ordered  4 no. of prod A and 3 no. of prod B so the total would be 7?

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct. It is the amount of the quantity of the products. I should change that name.

Comment: I would suggest you the create a bean class for the order...it will a better approach...otherwise the answer from @kaushal28 is correct

Comment: @RanjanK.M. Sir I have a question, I can add kaushal28's answer in my MainActivity class right, then just convert it back to string and show it in the desired textview right sir? Or am I wrong?.

Comment: Yup that's correct

Comment: @Yup got it working sir. Thanks again sir for all the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple if you've all prices listed in your array list named `orderTotal`. Iterate over the list and add all the values as following:

```
int total = 0;
for(String s : orderTotal){
   total += Integer.parseInt(s);
}
```

display this `total` wherever you want. If price is float, then use `Float.parseFloat(YOUR_FLOAT_STRING)`;

Comment: Sir I have a question, I can add this line my MainActivity class right, then just convert it back to string and show it in the desired textview right sir? Or am I wrong?. Please bear with me sir, I am still kind of learning haha

Comment: Sir I have runned using it and it returns zero. But when I add the line just after getting data from the SQLITE database it crashes sir. Why is that?

Comment: WHOOPS scratch that sir. I forgot my prices are in double haha.. You are Correct, thanks for the help sir. I really apprecciate it!